# access node.js server from domain name

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node.js can created a hello world server, here is the code `server.js`

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

I can access `localhost:8888` from my server machine but I can't access `ip:8888` from another machine and I also can't access `domainname:8888`. What is the problem?

Comment: You have to open the port in your firewall(s)

Comment: this looks like a firewall problem or a network configuration problem, maybe your router blocks internal traffic on the ports

Comment: What OS are you using?